# Upload Resize Image CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm setting up the upload file before add resize code. And its normally process, but after adding resize code my controller isn't working. Can you help me with this? I'm trying but it didn't work.

And my another problem, I can't upload image file size more than 2MB.

This for my work on online shop.

```
public function submit_image()
{
    $input_name = $_POST['input_name'];
    $input_email = $_POST['input_email'];
    $input_code_transaction = $_POST['input_code_transaction'];

    $config['file_name'] = $input_code_transaction;
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['upload_path']          = './img/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']             = 50000000;
    $config['max_width']            = 6000;
    $config['max_height']           = 4000;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if(!empty($_FILES['filefoto']['name'])) {
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('doc')) {
            $gbr = $this->upload->data();
            //Compress Image
            $config['image_library']='gd2';
            $config['source_image']='./img/'.$gbr['file_name'];
            $config['create_thumb']= FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio']= FALSE;
            $config['quality']= '50%';
            $config['width']= 1280;
            $config['height']= 720;
            $config['new_image']= './img/'.$gbr['file_name'];
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->resize();        

    $data = $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    $input_picture = $this->upload->do_upload('doc');
                }
        }
 }
```

Comment: The 2MB file upload is a setting in the php.config you need to change the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size limits.

Comment: And I suppose gd2 is not installed or activated on your server (localhost)

Comment: when you say stopped working, have you an error message? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings/5438125

Comment: wait im check this, and for error message no i didnt have just blank white screen @RichardHousham

Comment: where to activate gd2 on CodeIgniter? @VincentDecaux

Comment: gd2 is a module that you have to add to php. You normally do it on install, but you can activate it later. Google "gd2 php and whatever operating system you are using"

Comment: Regards the error have you checked your error log php_error.log

Comment: im done with upload max 2MB, but for gd2 i didnt find it to activated or install. and how i do to check this gd2 on or off in my php setting? @RichardHousham

Comment: create a page with the code <?php phpinfo(); ?> that will show you all your php settings.

Comment: did you set upload_max_filesize? if you use linux ubuntu, u can find in /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini and found upload_max_filesize, default is 2 MB

Comment: you all are missing the fact OP is trying to resize using the upload library not the image lib library

Comment: thanks for info, but im done for max file upload :D @HipHura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upload library has no inbuilt features for image resizing.

This whole section:

```
$config['image_library']='gd2';
            $config['source_image']='./img/'.$gbr['file_name'];
            $config['create_thumb']= FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio']= FALSE;
            $config['quality']= '50%';
            $config['width']= 1280;
            $config['height']= 720;
            $config['new_image']= './img/'.$gbr['file_name'];
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->resize();        

    $data = $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    $input_gambar = $this->upload->do_upload('doc');
```

needs to reference `image_lib` the image resizer codeigniter uses: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

So:

```
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('doc')) {
        $gbr = $this->upload->data();
        //Compress Image


        $imlib['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $imlib['source_image'] = './img/' . $gbr['file_name'];
        $imlib['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $imlib['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $imlib['quality'] = '50%';
        $imlib['width'] = 1280;
        $imlib['height'] = 720;
        $imlib['new_image'] = './img/resized_' . $gbr['file_name'];
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $imlib);
        if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
            show_error($this->image_lib->display_errors());
        }
        $yourouputimage = './img/resized_' . $gbr['file_name'];
    }
```

Comment: Okay, i will try this broo

Comment: why when i input this code, my proccess page HTTP ERROR 500? im using php with framework codeigniter :(  @Alex

Comment: turn on error reporting. in index.php make sure environment is development. without an exact error it is impossible to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: you don't post an answer if that answer is asking another question. you accept an answer if it answered your specific question, and then you ask a new question otherwise this site would be chaos

Comment: im sorry, i will fix it